# Shopify & Alpine.js how to render a collection for button that is clicked

Tags: shopify, liquid, alpine.js

Thanks for having a look.

What I have so far is I loop thru blocks created in admin and render each as a button. I set an x-data boolean which does render the collections but it toggles all on and off because the boolean is not unique. This is where I am struggling. Not sure how to create a unique selector.

```
<div x-data="{ selected: false }" class="tw-container tw-mx-auto tw-pt-20" x-cloak>
  <div class="tw-flex lg:tw-justify-center tw-space-x-4 tw-overflow-x-auto">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      <button
        type="button"
        @click="selected = !selected"
        class="tw-cursor-pointer"
      >
        // renders Image & title
      </button>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
    <div class="tw-container">
      <div
        x-show="selected"
      >
        <div class="tw-mt-12 tw-grid tw-grid-cols-1 md:tw-grid-cols-3 tw-gap-6">
          {% assign coll_name = block.settings['menu-collection-name'] | handleize %}
          {%- if coll_name != '' -%}
            // This renders all collections & toggles on/off
            {% for product in collections[coll_name].products %}
              {%- render 'restaurant-menu-item', item: product -%}
            {% endfor %}
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Restaurant Menu",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "Upload Menu Image"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Title",
      "default": "Menu"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "menu-link",
      "name": " Menu-link",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "link-image",
          "label": "Link Image"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "link-title",
          "label": "Link Title",
          "default": "Menu Title"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "menu-collection-name",
          "label": "Menu Collection Name (required)",
          "info": "It should match name of collection used for menu items. Use name when collection is first set"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Edit here is a refactor using a getter in Alpine x-data at the moment still can't figure out how to just render the collection for button clicked I tried to assign the collection name in each loop & compare but that does not work even though the collection name renders correctly in loop see comment in code below

```
<div
  x-data="
    {open: false,
      get isOpen() { return this.open },
      toggle() { this.open = ! this.open },
    }
  "
  class="tw-container tw-mx-auto tw-pt-20"
  x-cloak
>
  <div class="tw-flex lg:tw-justify-center tw-space-x-4 tw-overflow-x-auto">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      {%- comment -%}
         This below outputs the collection name for correct collection But if you assign or capture it only renders once &
        does not change
      {%- endcomment -%}
      {{ block.settings['menu-collection-name'] }}
      <button
        type="button"
        @click="toggle()"
        class="tw-cursor-pointer"
      >
        <div class="tw-min-w-[300px] sm:tw-max-w-sm tw-rounded-lg tw-p-6 tw-mb-6 tw-overflow-hidden tw-shadow">
          Renders image buton to be selected
        </div>
      </button>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="tw-container">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      {%- comment -%}
         This below outputs the collection name for correct collection, But if you assign or capture it only renders once &
        does not change
      {%- endcomment -%}
      {{ block.settings['menu-collection-name'] }}
      <div
        x-show="isOpen"
      >
        <div class="tw-mt-12 tw-grid tw-grid-cols-1 md:tw-grid-cols-3 tw-gap-6">
          {% assign coll_name = block.settings['menu-collection-name'] | handleize %}
          {%- if coll_name != '' -%}
            {% for product in collections[coll_name].products %}
              {%- render 'restaurant-menu-item', item: product -%}
            {% endfor %}
          {%- else -%}
            <p>No menu here check the name of collection</p>
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Restaurant Menu",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "Upload Menu Image"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Title",
      "default": "Menu"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "menu-link",
      "name": " Menu-link",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "link-image",
          "label": "Link Image"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "Link Title",
          "default": "Menu Title"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "menu-collection-name",
          "label": "Menu Collection Name (required)",
          "info": "It should match name of collection used for menu items. Use name when collection is first set"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help on the Shopify partner slack and wanted to share my result incase it’s helpful to others.

Maybe I was trying to kill a mosquito with a sledge hammer. From the beginning I kinda went against current dawn theme conventions mainly because I did not want to navigate to another page to view and toggle between collections.

I think a stumbling block from the beginning for me was I had this vision that no menu’s would be open until a button was clicked. Actually the way that was suggested to me resulted in a better user experience in that an initial open menu and ability to toggle between menus is quite nice for the user.

Here is what solved my problem.

In using Alpine.js to manage the state of what is rendered on the page. I initially thought  all menu’s initial state should be closed, turns out.

1 menu being open is a better user experience. To accomplish this x-data is set to x-data=“{ activeTab: 1 }” [x- data Alpine Docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data)

2 Set the click handler in button to @click=“activeTab = {{ forloop.index }}”  [x-on Alpine Docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on)

3 Set x-show to render selected menu to x-show=“activeTab == {{ forloop.index }}”   [x-show Alpine Docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/show)